# Deploying Spartacus in CCV2

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am having some issues with starting spartacus in production mode in CCV2.

Can anyone walk me through with what are the steps to do so? Can you configure the build/deploy process in CCV2 to achieve ( adding configurations when building/starting the storefront) or is there something out of the box?

P.S Currently, there are several other environments for development purposes that are being used.

I have also looked at - https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/contributor-setup/#building-and-running-spartacus-in-production-mode
but this is for contributors

Answer (score 1):

Here is a public repository showing how Spartacus can be deployed to ccv2, which can be found here. https://github.com/SAP-samples/cloud-commerce-sample-setup

Unless you have the proper credentials, you can take a look at a more in-depth steps using the following link

https://wiki.wdf.sap.corp/wiki/display/spar/Deploying+Spartacus+to+CCv2